# Data homogenization - SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to generate a lot of SQL request, like a tool, to transform a lot of data from a SQL Database ?

Basically I would like to homogenize some datatables following this way :

- Rename every title following this regex "REGEX" (just an update, so it's ok with sql)
- Update every duplicata changing an id then delete it (it's ok with sql too but really time consuming !)
- Update a line and delete the child line according to a list of label to change (I think it's not clear enough, basically I have a docx file with a big list of particular line to update and some to delete, and THIS is the really time consuming task)

So if you know a way to automize this kind of work, or a tool to do it, I would appreciate your help.

I tried with an excel file, but it is really time consuming ..

Comment: Can you be more specific and maybe give an example for every class of change you'd want to perform? Is your question about changing data only or is it about changing structure? Regarding your first point, would you like to rename a table or rename the content of a column named `title`? Is a `duplicata` referencing a second table with same content or is this about removing duplicate rows of a table?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do this, which tool(s) do you have available, and also is it a task you have to do only once, or will you run it often? The scripting language of Oracle database is called `PL/SQL` and should allow you to do all the tasks you mentioned.